# Symfony2 form type entity add extra option

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity

I have the following Symfony form field, it's a drop down that loads from an entity:

```
->add('measureunit', 'entity', array('label' => 'Measure Unit',
            'class' => 'TeamERPBaseBundle:MeasureUnit',
            'expanded' => false, 'empty_value' => '',
            'multiple' => false, 'property' => 'abreviation'
        ))
```

As you can see I have added `'empty_value' => ''` and everything works fine. Now, what I want is to have an extra option at the end to add a let say `new measure unit`. In other words the dropdown should display all the content of my entity, the empty value and other extra option called `new measure unit` or what ever I want to call it. Is it possible?

**Edit:** The whole form type file has this:

```
<?php
namespace TeamERP\StoresBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
class ProductType  extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('label'=>'Product name', 'required' => true,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('code', 'text', array('label'=>'Code', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('description', 'text', array('label'=>'Description', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('cost', 'money', array('label'=>'Cost', 'divisor' => 100, 'currency' => 'BWP'))
        ->add('category', new CategoryType(), array('required' => false))
        ->add('measureunit', 'entity', array('label' => 'Measure Unit',
            'class' => 'TeamERPBaseBundle:MeasureUnit',
            'expanded' => false, 'placeholder' => '',
            'multiple' => false, 'property' => 'abreviation'
        ))
        ->add('qtyToPurchase', 'number', array('label'=>'Quantity to purchase', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('reorderPoint', 'number', array('label'=>'Reorder point', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('qtyOnSalesOrder', 'number', array('label'=>'Quantity on sales order', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')));
    }
public function getName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $new_choice = new ChoiceView(array(), 'add', 'add new'); // <- new option
        $view->children['measureunit']->vars['choices'][] = $new_choice;//<- adding the new option 
    }
}
```

Error:
`Compile Error: Declaration of TeamERP\StoresBundle\Form\Type\ProductType::finishView() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::finishView(Symfony\Component\Form\FormView $view, Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form, array $options)`

**Edit2** Working form file:

```
<?php
namespace TeamERP\StoresBundle\Form\Type;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView; 
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView;
class ProductType  extends AbstractType 
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
        ->add('name', 'text', array('label'=>'Product name', 'required' => true,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('code', 'text', array('label'=>'Code', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('description', 'text', array('label'=>'Description', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('cost', 'money', array('label'=>'Cost', 'divisor' => 100, 'currency' => 'BWP'))
        ->add('category', new CategoryType(), array('required' => false))
        ->add('measureunit', 'entity', array('label' => 'Measure Unit',
            'class' => 'TeamERPBaseBundle:MeasureUnit',
            'expanded' => false, 'placeholder' => '',
            'multiple' => false, 'property' => 'abreviation'
        ))
        ->add('qtyToPurchase', 'number', array('label'=>'Quantity to purchase', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('reorderPoint', 'number', array('label'=>'Reorder point', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')))
        ->add('qtyOnSalesOrder', 'number', array('label'=>'Quantity on sales order', 'required' => false,
        'attr' => array('class' => 'form-control')));
    }
public function getName()
    {
        return 'product';
    }
public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $new_choice = new ChoiceView(array(), 'add', 'add new'); // <- new option
        $view->children['measureunit']->vars['choices'][] = $new_choice;//<- adding the new option 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

In your form type override the function [`finishView`](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Form/Extension/Core/Type/TimezoneType.html#method_finishView):

```
public function buildForm(FormbuilderInterface $builder, array $options){
    $builder->add('measureunit', EntityType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Measure Unit',
        'class' => 'TeamERPBaseBundle:MeasureUnit',
        'expanded' => false, 
        'empty_value' => '',
        'multiple' => false, 
        'property' => 'abbreviation'
    ));
}

public function finishView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    $newChoice = new ChoiceView(array(), 'add', 'Add New'); // <- new option
    $view->children['measureunit']->vars['choices'][] = $newChoice;//<- adding the new option 
}
```

You will get a new option 'add new' with value 'add' to the bottom of the field.

Comment: Thanks, I get this error: `Compile Error: Declaration of TeamERP\StoresBundle\Form\Type\ProductType::finishView() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::finishView(Symfony\Component\Form\FormView $view, Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface $form, array $options)`

Comment: I think your are missing to import the `FormView` and `FormInterface` components , try adding those two lines to the use list `use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;`

Comment: Thank you it worked, I just had to add this as well: `use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\View\ChoiceView;`

Comment: Of note: as this value is not part of the initial list (will produce a validation error), you'll need to either (1) "deal" with it on JS so the server never sees it, or (2) use a data transformer to "deal" with.

Comment: @DarrylHein The easiest way is to deal with listener.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to accepted answer:

If you choose the added option you will get validation error (because it's not valid entity), the following snippet can be used to overcome this error:

```
$builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            if ($event->getData() === 'add') {
                $event->setData(null);
            }
        }
    );
```

Then you can check if selected option is NULL, if it's => take value from additional input field.

Comment: Can you explain this comment further?

"Then you can check if selected option is NULL, if it's => take value from additional input field."

Thanks!

Comment: What I mean is => If you select that additional option you will receive validation error from Symfony itself -> that's why if selected value is 'add' - we replace it by NULL - so symfony will not throw validation error. Then you can check - If value of field is NULL -> then do your logic.