# Add placeholder or empty value to Entity Type with multiple = true in Symfony

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, placeholder

I want to do this:

```
 $builder->add('participants', EntityType::class, array(
        'label' => 'Teilnehmer',
        'class' => SchoolUser::class,
        'multiple' => true,
        'choices' => $this->getParticipantsOfEntry($builder),
        'empty_value'       => 'All',
        'empty_data'        => null,
        'preferred_choices' => array(null)
    ));
```

But I get no selected 'All' - field at all. This should not be hard, I wonder where is my mistake?

```
'placeholder' = 'All',
```

did also not work for me.

How can I do this?

Comment: Sadly nop! `placeholder` option is only applies if the `multiple` option is set to `false`. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#placeholder

Comment: Fuck, and there is no possiblity to do something like that? Can´t belive it :D

Comment: What about doing it through the finishView() method? I am struggling to find documentation on it but https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30013719/symfony2-form-type-entity-add-extra-option describes using it to add a new option at the end of the choices.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question was 4-months ago but I ran into a similar problem so thought I would share my solution in case it helps others.

First in the Form object:

```
class MealFormType extends AbstractType {
  public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options ) {
    $builder->add( 'courses', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => MealCourse::class,
            'multiple' => true,
            ) );
    $builder->addEventListener( FormEvents::PRE_SUBMIT, function( FormEvent $event ) {
        // Remove added entries here... maybe something like
        $data = $event->getData();
        if( ($key = array_search( 'all', $data['courses'] ) ) !== false ) {
            unset( $data['courses'][$key] );
            $event->setData( $data );
        }
    } );
  }
  public function configureOptions( OptionsResolver $resolver ) {
    $resolver->setDefaults( ['data_class' => Meal::class] );
  }
  public function finishView( FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options) {
    $newChoice = new ChoiceView( null, 'all', 'I want them all!' );
    array_unshift( $view->children['courses']->vars['choices'], $newChoice );
  }
}
```

This creates the form with multiple meal courses that can be selected, such as appetizer, soup, salad, entree, coffee, desert, ... using the `buildForm()` method. Also in this method an event listener for the PRE_SUBMIT event is added whose job it will be to remove any choices we have added since they are probably not real (if they were, we wouldn't have to add them in this painful way).

It sets the data_class as usual in `configureOptions()`.

Lastly it provides the `finishView()` method that creates a new choice with value of **'all'** that will display as **'I want them all'** in the select, then adds it at the beginning for the 'choices' array for the 'courses' form entry (this would be `$view->children['courses']->vars['choices'][] = $newChoice;` to put it at the end).

Ok, this is fine but it really doesn't do anything more than having an additional option to click or unclick. To use this we need some Javascript to manage the form. I just stuck this Javascript in the bottom of my Twig file and use jQuery.

The Twig file:

```
{% block body %}
  {{ form_start(mealForm) }}
    {{ form_row(mealForm.courses,
       {'attr': {'class': 'js-meal_course-select'}}) }}
    <button type="submit">Save</button>
  {{ form_end(mealForm) }}
{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
  {{ parent() }}

  <script>
    var mealCourseAllSelected = false;

    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
      // This will be called whenever an entry is selected or deselected
      $('.js-meal_course-select').change( function() {
        var selectedSet = $(this).val();
        if( mealCourseAllSelected  &&
            (selectedSet.length != $(this).get(0).options.length - 1 ||
             selectedSet.includes( 'all' )) ) {
          var opts = $(this).get(0).options;
          var len = opts.length;
          for( var i = 0; i < len; ++i ) {
            if( opts[i].value == 'all' ) opts[i].selected = false;
          }
          mealCourseAllSelected = false;
        } else if( selectedSet.includes( "all" )  ||
                   selectedSet.length == $(this).get(0).options.length - 1 ) {
          $('.js-meal_course-select option').prop( 'selected', true );
          mealCourseAllSelected = true;
        }
      }
    );
  </script>
{% endblock %}
```

The JavaScript responds to changes to what is selected. If the select option with the value of **'all'** is in the selected set, then all the select options are marked as selected, and a flag is set to say so. This is also done if everything is selected except the **'all'** entry because that is kind of the definition of *all*.

If the 'all are selected' flag is set and there is a change, then that change must be deselecting at least one, unless that one is the select option with the value of **'all'**, it deselects the selection option with the value of **'all'** and clears the 'all are selected' flag. If all are selected and the user tries to unselect just the select option with the value of **'all'**, it is just reselected.